# First run, div removed, secound run, div not removed. popup "lightbox"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a sort of lightbox thinkie. Its a learning experience so I dont want to use fancybox etc.

My problem is: 
I have 2 links. Each opens up an overlay and on top a white box with content. 
This works. 
When I close, only the first link, that opens a whitebox, closes both whitebox and overlay. The secound link only closes the overlay, not the whitebox. :S 
How come?

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<title>Box</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="whitebox.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="div0">
   box0   
</div> 

<div id="box0" class="box">
    <a class="closeBtn">X</a>
    <h1>box0</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div>Your email: <input type="text"></div>
        <br />
        <div>Message: <input type="textarea"></div>
    </form>

</div>

<div id="div1">
   box1    
</div> 

<div id="box1" class="box">
    <a class="closeBtn">X</a>
    <h1>box1</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div>Your email: <input type="text"></div>
        <br />
        <div>Message: <input type="textarea"></div>
    </form>

</div>

    <div class="pageOverlay"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

whitebox.js:

```
var state = 0;


function startOverlay(id){

if(state == 0){
    $(".pageOverlay").css({"opacity": "0.85"});
    $(".pageOverlay").fadeIn("fast");
    $(id).fadeIn("fast");

    state = 1;
}
}

//closes the overlay and box
function closeBox(id){

if(state == 1){     
    $(".pageOverlay").fadeOut("fast");
    $(id).fadeOut("fast");
    state = 0;
}
}

function centerBox(id){
//alert(id);
var browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var boxHeight = $(id).height();
var boxWidth = $(id).width();

$(id).css({"position": "absolute","top": (browserHeight / 2) - (boxHeight /                2),"left": (browserWidth / 2) - (boxWidth / 2)});

}

function runBox(link, id){
$(link).click(function(){
    startOverlay(id); 
    centerBox(id);
});

//this function closes the overlay when user clicks "close"
$(".closeBtn").click(function(){
    closeBox(id);
});

//this function closes the overlay when user clicks outside the message area
$(".pageOverlay").click(function(){
    closeBox(id);
});
}
//Makes sure the document is fully loaded. 
$(document).ready(function(){
runBox("#div0","#box0");
runBox("#div1","#box1");
});
```

style.css:

```
#div0{
margin-top:150px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid black;
cursor: pointer;
width: 150px;
}
#div1{
margin-top:150px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid black;
cursor: pointer;
width: 150px;
}
.pageOverlay{
display:none;
position:fixed;
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#000000;
z-index:1000;
}
.box{
display:none;
position:relative;
height:450px;
width:450px;
background:#ffffff;
border:2px solid #a0a0a0;
z-index:2000;
padding:12px;
font-size:14px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.box h1{
text-align:left;
color:#7FA5FE;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:700;
border-bottom:1px solid #a0a0a0;
padding-bottom:2px;
margin-bottom:20px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.box a{
cursor: pointer;    
}
.box p{
text-align:center;
}

.closeBtn{
font-size:12px;
line-height:14px;
right:6px;
top:4px;
position:absolute;
color:#7FA5FE;
font-weight:700;
display:block;
#div0{
margin-top:150px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid black;
cursor: pointer;
width: 150px;
}
#div1{
margin-top:150px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid black;
cursor: pointer;
width: 150px;
}
.pageOverlay{
display:none;
position:fixed;
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#000000;
z-index:1000;
}
.box{
display:none;
position:relative;
height:450px;
width:450px;
background:#ffffff;
border:2px solid #a0a0a0;
z-index:2000;
padding:12px;
font-size:14px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.box h1{
text-align:left;
color:#7FA5FE;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:700;
border-bottom:1px solid #a0a0a0;
padding-bottom:2px;
margin-bottom:20px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.box a{
cursor: pointer;    
}
.box p{
text-align:center;
}

.closeBtn{
font-size:12px;
line-height:14px;
right:6px;
top:4px;
position:absolute;
color:#7FA5FE;
font-weight:700;
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Could you supply working demo on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: nice tool, sure: http://jsfiddle.net/JB7aP/

Comment: This is far too much code. Make a _testcase_.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to keep state, because if overlay is here you can't click on incorrect button,
2. you used selectors while  you just need to make `box` var only once,
3. As you use one overlay element, you need to bind click event every time for it, (see `one()` I used
4. It is better to use `$(document).ready(function() {})` for whole your code to keep global scope clean.
5. I made a trick to bind click on one element only and trigger it by other one, to not having duplicate event runners.

here the [fixed code](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/r627f/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
function startOverlay(box) {
    $(".pageOverlay").css({
        "opacity": "0.85"
    });
    $(".pageOverlay").fadeIn("fast");
    box.fadeIn("fast");
}

//closes the overlay and box


function closeBox(box) {
    $(".pageOverlay").fadeOut("fast");
    box.fadeOut("fast");
}

function centerBox(box) {
    //alert(id);
    var browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var boxHeight = box.height();
    var boxWidth = box.width();

    box.css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": (browserHeight / 2) - (boxHeight / 2),
        "left": (browserWidth / 2) - (boxWidth / 2)
    });

}
 //trigger click on close button by click on pageOverlay, to not duplicate events
 $(".pageOverlay").bind("click", function() {
     $('.closeBtn:visible').click();
        });
    
    
function runBox(link, id) {
    var box = $(id);
    $(link).click(function() {
        startOverlay(box);
        centerBox(box);
        //this function closes the overlay when user clicks "close" or outside of area
        //bind to only visible button
        $(".closeBtn:visible").one("click",function() {
            closeBox(box);
        })

    });


}

    runBox("#div0", "#box0");
    runBox("#div1", "#box1");
});​
```

I can also suggest to generate dialog content instead of having several elements in DOM

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is when binding the event handlers: If you try this:

```
//this function closes the overlay when user clicks outside the message area
$(".pageOverlay").click(function(){
    alert(id); //Or better console.log(id)
    closeBox(id);
});
```

You will see that any of the links triggers the function closeBox *twice*, this is because you are really calling the event bind twice. Try eliminating the `runBox()` function:

```
//Makes sure the document is fully loaded. 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#div0').click(function(){
        startOverlay('#box0'); 
        centerBox('#box0');
    });

    $('#div1').click(function(){
        startOverlay('#box1'); 
        centerBox('#box1');
    });

    //this function closes the overlay when user clicks "close"
    //Note: you can bind both on the same call
    $(".closeBtn,.pageOverlay").click(function(){
        if(jQuery('#box0:visible').length>0){
            closeBox('#box0');
        }else{
            closeBox('#box1');
        }
    });

});​
```

Comment: if boxes more than two you plan to make a set of `if () {} else if() {}` ?

Comment: No really, I just wanted to answer his question: Why second box doesn't close? But you are definitively right, your approach is more flexible if there are going to be more boxes/dialogs to show.